# Mixed and specifig aligment for table using tabular(x)

Tags: tables

Is it possible to specify the alignment for each single column?

I have this table:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{*{5}{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}X}}
    \toprule
    & \textbf{1990-2009} & \textbf{2010} & \textbf{2011} & \textbf{2012} \\
    \midrule
    Argentinien & 143 & 3.100 & 2.450 & 600 \\
    Brasilien & 255 & 9.563 & 5.676 & 6.066,63 \\
    Chile & ... & 5 & ... & 76 \\
    Kolumbien & 1.677 & 6 & 293 & 996 \\
    Ecuador & 1.619 & 45 & 59 & 96 \\
    Mexiko & 146 & 9 & 2 & 74 \\
    Peru & 2.262 & 94 & 929 & 1.306,94 \\
    Venezuela & 240 & 900 & ... & ... \\
    Gesamt & 6.352 & 13.712 & 9.309 & 9.206 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

but I would like to specify the first column to be left-aligned opposed to the right-alignment of the other columns. Putting a `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{l*{4}{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}X}}` breaks the table because then it does not span the entire width like now. In fact I am trying to have a table like on page 11 of this pdf: http://repositorio.cepal.org/bitstream/handle/11362/35927/S2013956_en.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: `>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X *{4}{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}X}` However, my usual advice is to typeset tables at their natural width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\raggedright` for the first column and `\raggedleft` for the other ones.

However, I usually recommend typesetting tables at their natural width; here I present a realization with `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,siunitx}

\sisetup{group-four-digits}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{
  >{\raggedright}X
  *{4}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
}
\toprule
& \textbf{1990-2009} & \textbf{2010} & \textbf{2011} & \textbf{2012} \\
\midrule
Argentinien & 143 & 3.100 & 2.450 & 600 \\
Brasilien & 255 & 9.563 & 5.676 & 6.066,63 \\
Chile & ... & 5 & ... & 76 \\
Kolumbien & 1.677 & 6 & 293 & 996 \\
Ecuador & 1.619 & 45 & 59 & 96 \\
Mexiko & 146 & 9 & 2 & 74 \\
Peru & 2.262 & 94 & 929 & 1.306,94 \\
Venezuela & 240 & 900 & ... & ... \\
\midrule
Gesamt & 6.352 & 13.712 & 9.309 & 9.206 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=4.0]
  S[table-format=5.0]
  S[table-format=4.0]
  S[table-format=4.2]
}
\toprule
& \textbf{1990-2009} & \textbf{2010} & \textbf{2011} & \textbf{2012} \\
\midrule
Argentinien &  143 & 3100 & 2450 &  600 \\
Brasilien   &  255 & 9563 & 5676 & 6066,63 \\
Chile       & {--} &    5 & {--} &   76 \\
Kolumbien   & 1677 &    6 &  293 &  996 \\
Ecuador     & 1619 &   45 &   59 &   96 \\
Mexiko      &  146 &    9 &    2 &   74 \\
Peru        & 2262 &   94 &  929 & 1306,94 \\
Venezuela   &  240 &  900 & {--} & {--} \\
\midrule
Gesamt & 6352 & 13712 & 9309 & 9206 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or the best of both worlds (here I added the period as separator for thousands and the comma for the decimal part):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,siunitx}

\sisetup{
  group-four-digits,
  group-separator={.},
  output-decimal-marker={,},
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{
  @{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=4.0]
  S[table-format=5.0]
  S[table-format=4.0]
  S[table-format=4.2]
}
\toprule
& \textbf{1990-2009} & \textbf{2010} & \textbf{2011} & \textbf{2012} \\
\midrule
Argentinien &  143 & 3100 & 2450 &  600 \\
Brasilien   &  255 & 9563 & 5676 & 6066,63 \\
Chile       & {--} &    5 & {--} &   76 \\
Kolumbien   & 1677 &    6 &  293 &  996 \\
Ecuador     & 1619 &   45 &   59 &   96 \\
Mexiko      &  146 &    9 &    2 &   74 \\
Peru        & 2262 &   94 &  929 & 1306,94 \\
Venezuela   &  240 &  900 & {--} & {--} \\
\midrule
Gesamt & 6352 & 13712 & 9309 & 9206 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you might want to set `output-decimal-marker = {,}` in your second case (or even `copy-decimal-marker`) as otherwise you get funny things like 1.306.94